# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, eloquent

I'm trying to post an image from a **one to many** relationship while also doing the CRUD (create part), but I am having some trouble doing it. I keep on getting this error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create()` must be of the type array, object given, called in

Whenever I try to use associate to define the relationship together with **`user_info`** with **`user_image`** table. I have already used the array function to make it into an array but it still gave me this error. So what should I do?

**createController:**

```
public function create1(){

    return view('create1');
}

public function store1(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

 $user_info = Session::get('data');
      $UserImage = new UserImage($request->input()) ;


     if($file = $request->hasFile('input_img')) {
      $file = array();

        $file = $request->file('input_img') ;
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $UserImage->userImage = $fileName ;
        $UserImage = UserImage::create($file);
        $UserImage->user_infos()->associate($user_info);
    }

    $UserImage->save() ;

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

**HomeController**(this is where I print out my information)

```
public function getInfo($id) {

  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
```

**blade.php** (how I show the image in view)

```
 @foreach ($data3 as $object9)
 <img width="100" height="100" src="{!! $object9->signature !!}">
    @endforeach
```

**UserImage model**(in table I used binary format to store in DB)

```
    class UserImage extends Eloquent
    {
            protected $fillable = array('userImage','user_id');
        public function user_infos() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\user_info', 'user_id', 'id');
        }

class user_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name');
    protected $table = user_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        public function UserImages() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserImage','user_id');
    }
}
```

**create1.blade.php**(this is how I upload the image)

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        {{  csrf_field()  }}


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input data-preview="#preview" name="input_img" type="file" id="imageInput">
            <img class="col-sm-6" id="preview"  src="" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It is saying you are passing an object to the `create()` method when you **must** pass an array... This means you cannot do this `$UserImage = UserImage::create($file);`

Comment: But I did use an array by using this, $file = array();

Comment: No, you set a variable as an empty array and then overid this when you set it to the file.

Comment: @James I have updated my question based on Suraj answer but I am getting a new error could you help me take a look, tks a lot

Comment: You really should've asked that as another question, as now @suraj's answer makes no sense. Have you read through your code? Slow down and take some time to look through what is happening. You are creating a variable called `$file` as an array. And then what are you doing with it?

Comment: Ohh ok, I will revert it back to normal then ask another question then

Answer (score 1):

You should give an array while passing data to create method like this. Currently, you are passing the file object.

```
$UserImage = UserImage::create(['file' => $request->file('input_img')]);
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, tks for the quick reply, after using your answer I got this new error instead, "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array"

Comment: I suppose you are saving the file name the you should pass the  `$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;  $UserImage = UserImage::create(['userImage' => $fileName]);` . Make sure to mention the right db column name

Comment: Sry I don't quite get you, could you explain in a much more simpler term

Comment: H Suraj, I have changed the $request->file('input_img')]); to $request->file('$fileName')]); and I also check that it was on the right db coulmn